# Splitting a string by digit

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to split a string by digits vs everything else.

```
string = 'hello_there16.txt'
match = re.match(r"([a-z]+)([0-9]+)",string , re.I)
match.groups()
```

Expected output:

```
(hello_there,16,.txt)
```

However the output of `match` is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to split then you might use `re.split`:

```
import re
string = 'hello_there16.txt'
result = re.split("([0-9]+)", string)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['hello_there', '16', '.txt']
```